# Gnuplot: controlling colours and ranges of "set palette."

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot to make a colour-map. What I need is, when I set a palette I need to define the ranges and colours such that certain ranges have the same colour.

For example, say the third column of the data ranges from 100 to 150. I need 100 to 120 to be same colour, then 120 to 130 same colour. I tried doing it this way

```
set palette defined (100:120 "gray", 121:129 "blue", 130:150 "dark-gray")
```

But it gnuplot says this is **invalid expression**, specifically pointing at the " **:** ".

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check out `set palette maxcolors`.  From the help page:

> This option can also be used to separate levels of z=constant in discrete
>    steps, thus to emulate filled contours. Default value of 0 stays for
>    allocating all remaining entries in the terminal palette or for to use exact
>    mapping to RGB.

Also note that you should be able to do something like:

```
set palette defined ( 100 "gray", 120 "gray", 121 "blue", 129 "blue" )
```

but be careful -- the numbers 100, 120, 121, 129, etc don't correspond to the values on your colorbar unless you `set cbrange [100:129]` (for example).

Comment: By the way, is there any extensive manual for gnuplot that you recommend?

Comment: Not other than the builtin and online documentation (as well as the the demos).  http://www.gnuplot.info/documentation.html